# Loading PDFs or Images from URL into a CoverFlow view

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, coverflow

I want to load PDFs or Images into  a View, but when the source is an URL there might be connection lags, so I wonder what is the best approach when loading content (like magazines) into a Coverflow view in the iPhone?.
(For Coverflow, something like this: http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/ )

1. Is it ok to get a pdf file then
   obtain corresponding page images and
   show them in an appropriate
   resolution a Coverflow view?
   (Downloading the hole PDF might take
   long)
2. Or is better to download images as
   needed and then pass them to the
   Coverflow? (Although resolution
   might be a problem, hence maybe I
   wil need more than one image per
   page)
3. Would it be better to have a pdf
   file for every page?(So they can be
   rendered at any resolution and I
   don't have to download the hole file
   at once)

I hope you can give some advices on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record:
After some research I came up with images approach. They are the simpler, fastest, and reasonable good resolution. They can be loaded in 2 stages, regular resolution and better resolution for zooming, etc.